# Trying to generalize a property from UFD to GCD domains.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, divisibility

Let $D$ be a GCD domain, ie. the greatest common divisor of any pair of non-zero elements in $D$ always exists. I'm trying to prove or disprove the following conclusion which is valid when $D$ is a UFD:

> For any $d\in D$ and $n\in\mathbb Z^+$, there exist a $t\in D$ such that $\forall a\in D$, $d\mid a^n$ iff $t\mid a$.

If $D$ is an UFD, then we have a factorization $d=\alpha p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$, where $\alpha$ is a unit of $D$, $p_i$'s are distinct primes of $D$, $e_i$'s are positive integers. Apparently taking $t=p_1^{\lceil \frac{e_1}n \rceil}p_2^{\lceil \frac{e_2}n\rceil}\cdots p_k^{\lceil \frac{e_k}n\rceil}$ would meet the requirement.

When $D$ is just a GCD domain, intuitively I think this proposition is still valid, but I have no idea how to prove it. Anyone might help me?

Comment: Please give a source for your problem (or if you don't have one, admit it is your own invention.)  It wouldn't be nice to trick users into a wild goose chase, if there is some issue with the problem.

Comment: @rschwieb Well, I think from my wording it's pretty clear that I don't know the answer. If by tricking others into a wild goose chase you mean I might know the answer and intentionally don't mention it, I assure you that's not the case...

Comment: No, I mean posing a problem as if it can be solved, but you don’t actually know it can be solved. If it’s a conjecture be clear about it.

Comment: @rschwieb Well, it's either true or false, right? Are you suggesting that I should be clear I don't know how hard it is to solve it?...

Comment: One last time: knowing ahead of time if it had a solution and knowing how hard it is to solve are different things.  I think you can at least inform readers of the first one.

Comment: @rschwieb Then maybe this is my last time to respond you. You insist that some information is missing, that I should inform others if it had a solution. I take that means if anyone has already proven or disproven it before? But as I said in my first response, I don't know the answer and I'm not pretending to know in my wording. But if I already know someone has solved it before, how come I don't if it's true or false. I don't believe normal people can't infer this much, so what's the point?

Comment: It is very simple: if the source is YOU just say so, that it is a conjecture.  Right now it  could be ambiguous to some readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is true for any GCD, consider smooth functions on interval $(-1,1)$, the irreducibles are $x-a$(probably, im not 100% sure), the existence of [flat functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) will show that the conclusion is not true.

To be precise, let $D$ be the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra generated by $x$(a function) and all $\phi/x^i$ for integer $i$ $\ge 0$, where $\phi$ is the flat function $e^{-x^2}$. An element in $D$ is a polynomial of $x$ and $\frac{\phi}{x^N}$ for some $N$, gcd of any pair exists. Now take $d=\phi$ in your statement, if such $t$ exists, order of $t$  at $0$ is infinite, it is of the form $\frac{\phi}{x^N}p(x, \phi)$, then $t \nmid \frac{\phi}{x^{N+1}}=a$ but $\phi \mid a^n$.

Comment: Ive edited my answer to focus on a counter example and gave up on when the statement will be true

Comment: Your counterexample is correct and excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a counterexample : take any field $K$ and let $R$ be the polynomial ring generated by $X^{1/2^k}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then I think it is a GCD domain but that $X|a^3$ is not equivalent to $t|a$ whatever $t$ you choose in $R$.